# what is the meaning of 'might get him' in the following sentence

Tags: grammar

He felt nakedly unarmed, and wondered how far the serrated steak knife by his plate might get him. What is the meaning of this sentence

Comment: Hello, Nikhil. 'He' is or at least feels threatened, by nasty people near him, no doubt. 'he wondered how far the serrated steak knife by his plate might get him' means 'he wondered if he could get out of this tight spot with his only weapon being a steak knife'.

Comment: ***Nakedly*** *unarmed* as opposed to what? ***Equipped but*** *unarmed*? I would expect a phrase like ***markedly*** *unarmed*, but I don't have a clue what ***nakedly*** *unarmed* means.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the expression here means: He wondered how well he could defend himself using the steak knife as a weapon. To "go far" can have an idiomatic meaning of lasting or surviving in a given situation. So the knife, while not designed to be a weapon, could still help him "get far" in a dangerous situation.

Comment: *Nakedly unarmed* also implies that this person normally *is* armed with a weapon, i.e., feels naked with his gun/knife.